# When in physics we assume a quantity is constant over an interval dt, why/how is this justified?

Tags: calculus

Unsure about whether I should have posted it here or on the physics stackexchange, but since this feels to me more like a question about calculus, I have posted it here.

An example would be when we're finding the work done by a varying force $F(x)$ over some interval $[x_1,x_2]$. We assume that the force is constant over $\Delta x$ as we take the limit $\Delta x \to 0$. What I want to know is, what exactly is the mathematical assumption we're making here? I.e what quantity's limit is approaching zero or some quantity, as we take $\Delta x\to 0$. I want to know this so I know how to verify if this assumption is valid.

Comment: It is justified by the empirical experience that there are no leaps in a physical process. So, if the interval is extremely small, the force cannot change much within this interval, therefore we can assume a constant force.

Comment: @Peter So can any continuous process be assumed to be constant over a small interval?

Comment: Your questionning is legitimate, but if you have followed a lecture on the history of the development of the (infinitesimal) calculus, you know that it is these extremely "practical" **notations** (found by Leibniz) that have allowed the huge development of theoretical and applied analysis. These notations have an ambiguous side, yes. Logicians in the 20th century have developed a coherent "world" in which these "infinitesimals" make sense : it is "**non standard analysis**".

Comment: @Peter Thinking about it a bit more, this is probably the correct answer and about as good of an answer there is to this question. If you can post it in the answer section I'll select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first rephrase the question to make sure I understand it right. You have a function $F(x)$, and you are trying to find out what conditions are required on $F$ to assume that $F$ is constant over an infinitesimal interval.

Basically, you need to ensure that your function does not vary highly in suitable small intervals and that any change in $F$ that happened in $\Delta x$ should limit to $0$, as $\Delta x \to 0$. You would like to avoid $F$ from being functions such as, say, [Dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function#:%7E:text=of%20the%20set%20of%20rational,mathematician%20Peter%20Gustav%20Lejeune%20Dirichlet.).

Short answer : Yeah, as you have noted in a comment, continuity of $F$ seems to be a sufficient condition for this.

---

Slightly longer answer: Note that trying to make sense of this process of dividing up the domain into very small intervals, assuming $F$ is constant on that interval, and adding all the $F \Delta x$ up to form an approximation of what the integral (in this case, the Work) should be; such that it becomes a better and better approximation as $\Delta x \to 0$, is exactly what [Riemann integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral), and constructing Riemann integrals, are all about.

So the class of functions you are looking for is probably the class of Riemann integrable functions. But then, all the continuous functions on $\Bbb R$ are Riemann integrable, and thus checking for continuity is a sufficient condition for you in this case.

Comment: As a side question: Is this interpretation (i.e the condition that if $\Delta F \to 0$ over an interval when $\Delta x \to 0$, then we can treat the function as being constant in that interval) equivalent to the upper/lower Darboux sums interpretation given in the other answer here?

Comment: Was revisiting my old questions, found this, so I thought I'll answer the question in my comment for future visitors. Can't prove it, but an intuitive explanation of why these two might be equivalent is if the two sums converge, the difference between them is zero. One way this can happen, or one interpretation is, for an interval $(x_i, x_{i+1})$ within n divisions, the difference between $max_{x_i\le x\le x_{i+1}}F(x)$ and $min_{x_i\le x\le x_{i+1}}F(x)$ tends to zero, and so you can think of the function as roughly constant over it.

Answer (score 4):

The way the calculation works is a bit more subtle. Let's say the interval $[a,b]$ is given, and you want to calculate the work done by the force $F(x)$ as $x$ changes from $a$ to $b$.

We now *do* subdivide the interval $[a,b]$ into parts, which are usually equal (but sometimes inequal). This is done by placing additional points $a=x_0<x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n=b$. For example, set $x_i=a+\frac{b-a}{n}i$.

What we do *next* is not exactly keeping $F(x)$ constant on the intervals $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$ - this is sort of a simplification of what we *really* do.

Instead, on each of those intervals we take the *maximum* and the *minimum* force: the actual work done on $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$ by real $F(x)$ must be between $(x_{i+1}-x_i)\min_{x_i\le x\le x_{i+1}}F(x)$ and $(x_{i+1}-x_i)\max_{x_i\le x\le x_{i+1}}F(x)$. (For pedants: we are *really* taking the *supremum* and *infimum*, not *maximum* and *minimum*, but I will use the symbols $\max$, $\min$ throughout.)

Now we sum those across $i=0,1,2,\ldots,n-1$ to get something we call *lower Darboux sum* and *upper Darboux sum*:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(x_{i+1}-x_i)\min_{x_i\le x\le x_{i+1}}F(x)$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(x_{i+1}-x_i)\max_{x_i\le x\le x_{i+1}}F(x)$$

Now, if we can prove that those two sums converge to the same number as the division of $[a,b]$ grows finer and finer, then it is natural to call *that* number the *work done by $F(x)$ on $x\in[a,b]$*. Or, in maths, we call that the *Riemann integral of $F(x)$ on interval $[a,b]$* and denote it:

$$\int_a^b F(x)dx$$

More precisely, if the upper and lower Darboux sums exist for every subdivision of $[a,b]$ and converge to the same value as the maximum size of the intervals in the subdivision tends to $0$, then we call the function $F$ *Riemann-integrable*, and we call the common limit of the two sums the *Riemann integral* of $F(x)$ over $[a,b]$. Otherwise, we say that $F$ is not Riemann-integrable.

> **Side note**: If a function $F$ is Riemann-integrable on $[a,b]$, this automatically means that the method of keeping $F(x)$ *constant* on the intervals $[x_1,x_{i+1}]$ *also works*! Namely, as long as you pick $F(x)$ on each interval equal to *some* value of it on that interval (e.g. keep it equal to $F(x_i)$ or to $F(x_{i+1})$ or even to $\frac{1}{2}(F(x_i)+F(x_{i+1})$) - the sum you're getting is *between the lower and the upper Darboux sums*. That means that, having both the upper and lower Darboux sums converge to $\int_a^b F(x)dx$, *your* sum (squeeze theorem!) converges to the same value!

Back to the integration: why does it work in physics so well that you don't ever get to ask the question about Riemann integrability? I believe this mostly comes from the fact that (unlike some very hairy functions that we study in maths), in physics most functions are assumed to be well-behaved: normally continuous, often more than that (smooth - i.e. differentiable, often infinitely many times). So a theorem comes handy:

**Theorem**: Every continuous real function $F$ on $[a,b]$ is Riemann-integrable.

**Proof** (sketch): I won't go down to show the full proof here, but there is a bunch of prerequisites:

- Every continuous real function $F$ on a closed interval is *bounded*.

  - This means, for every subdivision $a=x_0<x_1<x_2\cdots<x_n=b$ of $[a,b]$ both the lower and upper Darboux sum make sense.
- Every continuous real function $F$ on a closed interval is *uniformly continuous*.

  - This is a condition often stronger than "just" being continuous, and it means that, if you pick a small $\epsilon>0$, you can always find the size $\delta>0$ of a small interval so that, whenever $|x-y|<\delta$ you have $F(x)-F(y)<\epsilon$. In other words, the values of $F$ come close "enough" to each other *across the whole interval* as the points on which you calculate $F$ come close "enough".

Because of the above uniform continuity, all of $\max_{x_i\le x\le x_{i+1}}F(x)$ and $\min_{x_i\le x\le x_{i+1}}F(x)$ are also smaller (or equal) than $\epsilon$ if we set $|x_i{+1}-x_i|<\delta$, so one can see that the upper and lower Darboux sums differ by at most $\epsilon(b-a)$. You see that you can now make that difference arbitrarily small by choosing $\epsilon$ arbitrarily small and then choosing the subdivision to be as fine as the corresponding $\delta$ (or finer).$\,\blacksquare$

This theorem is then extended in different directions:

- If a bounded function has finitely many discontinuities, it can still be proven to be Riemann-integrable.
- If a function is not bounded on $[a,b)$ but is Riemann-integrable on all $[a,c]$ with $a<c<b$, we may still try to define $\int_a^b F(x)dx:=\lim_{c\to b-}\int_a^c F(x)dx$ (if the limit exists) and we call that value an *improper* integral of $F$ on $[a,b)$. $b$ could be taken to be a finite real number or $+\infty$.
- There is a different definition of something called *Lebesgue integral*, which is a generalization of the previous two, although in fact it is more than "just" a generalization and covers many more pathological cases.

Anyways - the bottom line is that, as long as your force $F(x)$ is continuous (or has finitely many discontinuities), it is Riemann-integrable, and so your method works, and it produces the value of the Riemann integral $\int_a^b F(x)dx$, which (as we concluded above) is the only sensible number to call the "work done by this function".

Further reading:

- [Riemann integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral) (original definition)
- [Riemann-Darboux integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral) (an equivalent definition which is explored in this answer)
- [Improper integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral)
- [Lebesgue integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration)
- [Continuous functions are bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/140698/700480) (a question here, on MSE)
- [Uniform continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity#Properties)
- [How to prove that continuous functions are Riemann-integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/56393/700480) (another MSE question)

Comment: Although I selected the answer I saw first, this was great too. Putting this comment here so hopefully this can float up and people that visit this thread later on can see this too.

Comment: One question though: In physics, almost universally, and across textbooks the approach to solving problems involving a function varying over some x, is the "assume f is roughly constant" over the interval approach. What then is a good or correct interpretation to have in these cases? From your answer it appears that it just happens to by luck work out that way, rather than it being a valid physical interpretation of the situation

Comment: We are back to the handwavy world, but as long as the function is continuous on a closed interval, you can say that it is "*roughly constant on small intervals*" precisely because of that property called "uniform continuity" - you can make the intervals small enough ($\delta$) so that it cannot vary much (i.e. up to a given $\epsilon$) on any interval of that size contained in your original closed segment. Such intuition fails if the function is not continuous, say [$F(x)=\begin{cases}0&x=0\\\sin(1/x)&x\ne 0\end{cases}$ on $[0,1]$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%3Dsin%281%2Fx%29)

Comment: (even though the above function $F$ is properly [Riemann-integrable on $[0,1]$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5BSin%5B1%2Fx%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%5D) because it is bounded on $[0,1]$ and is discontinuous in only one point $x=0$.)

Comment: Alright, understood. Thanks

Comment: @xasthor Here is another line of thought to ponder... If your function $F(x)$ is *smooth* (i.e. has a *continuous* derivative) on $[a,b]$, then $F'(x)=dF/dx$ will be bounded on $[a,b]$, e.g. $|F(x)|\le M$ for some $M$. Now this implies ("[Mean Value Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)") that $|F(x)-F(y)|=|F'(\xi)||x-y|\le M|x-y|$ (where $\xi$ is between $x$ and $y$) so again, small changes in $x$ bring small changes in $F(x)$ across the whole interval (i.e. uniform continuity is satisfied). Maybe this is a more straightforward argument for you?

Comment: I understood the previous argument, but this makes sense too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate *motivations* from *definitions* (or *theorems*). This is I think unfortunately not clearly distinguished in introductory Physics explanations. We often gain our intuition and motivations when things are constant/piecewise constant, and then we use that insight to formulate a general definition/theorem.

For example, since middle/high school, we introduce the concept of *work done* (by a given force on a given object) to be the product of the force with the distant moved in the direction of the force. This idea makes a lot
sense when we look at “simple” everyday idealizations, e.g moving a ball from the ground to the top of a shelf etc. But, once you have this idea for constant forces, you can easily generalize the intuition to piecewise constant forces. Finally, once we have enough of an idea, we formulate a rigorous definition:

> **Definition.**
>
> Let $U\subset\Bbb{R}^n$ be an open set, $\mathbf{F}:U\to\Bbb{R}^n$ a continuous vector field, and $\gamma:[a,b]\to U$ a (piecewise) $C^1$ path. We define *the work done by $\mathbf{F}$ along the path $\gamma$*, $W_{\mathbf{F},\gamma}$, to be the line integral
> \begin{align}
> W_{\mathbf{F},\gamma}&:=\int_{\gamma}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{l}:=\int_a^b\mathbf{F}(\gamma(t))\cdot\gamma’(t),dt.
> \end{align}

If you only wish to focus on the one-dimensional case, this reduces to $\int_{x_1}^{x_2}F(x)\,dx$ (where the path starts at $x_1$ and ends at $x_2$).

So, this integral formula is just a definition! We as humans are allowed to make whatever definitions we like (as long as it doesn’t cause logical contradictions with the theory we have already developed). So, there is no longer any question of why we’re allowed to “assume forces are constant over $\Delta x$, and then take $\Delta x\to 0$“. A definition is a definition. However, you can ask why it is a good definition, and here some of the reasons are:

- It is a pretty general definition for work done by a force field, and as a result applies to a wide range of scenarios, and also due to the generality, it “unifies” many previously separate ideas. For instance, the definition makes no reference to any specific type of force field, i.e the definition applies equally well to gravitational fields, electricmagnetic fields, to frictional forces acting on a curved inclined ramp etc.
- One can easily see that in the case of constant/piecewise-constant forces and piecewise-linear paths, this definition reproduces what we already expect. So, it conforms to our intuition.
- A slightly more difficult-to-motivate reason is because the mathematical quantity $\int_{\gamma}\mathbf{F}\cdot \,d\mathbf{l}$ appears all over physics, so giving this quantity a name is convenient. Part of the reason this quantity appears all over is because Newton’s second law is given in ODE format: $\sum_i\mathbf{F}_i=m\mathbf{a}$ (now you can of course question why it is valid to describe nature using a second order ODE, but this is just an approximation… though a very good one for most everyday (and even slightly beyond) purposes. So in this sense, the definition is also physically reasonable). This is a vector quantity, so not necessarily easy to deal with, so one of the things we like to do is consider specific scalar quantities, and it has proven (by experience) to be useful to consider various integrated quantities (work done, kinetic energy, potential energy etc etc, and to consider relationships between them).

---

Above, I described the situation for the motiviation/definition of work done. We can make exactly the same argument for other things, like *mass of a rigid body, center of mass, moment of inertia* and so on. These are usually given by various integral formulae, whereby the motivation for these integral formulae comes by considering the case of constant/piecewise-constant/pointlike things. For mass/mass density specifically, you may find some of the remarks here [What does it mean to integrate with respect to mass?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/605972/203278) helpful (but be warned, that answer was intentionally written at a higher level of math sophistication).

Answer (score 0):

This, to me, looks similar to the analogy used to explain that the Riemann integral is a “good approximation” of the area underneath a function: if you take $\Delta x\to 0$ you are taking such a small interval that the function changes value so little that considering it constant is a good approximation: thus you can approximate the area underneath a function with the sum of many little rectangulars.

Note that I chose the analogy with the integral because the work done by a changing force is actually the integral of the force function, over the time interval that you’re interested in.

For visual intuition, see https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Somme-superiori.png#/media/File:Somme-superiori.png

Comment: Sorry, but it is still "handwaving" : the asker asks for more rigor...

Answer (score 0):

Riemann integration has 'upper sums' and 'lower sums'.  They get introduced in university mathematics.
Divide the interval $[x_1,x_2]$ into $n$ intervals, so $\Delta x=(x_2-x_1)/n$.
Let $m_i$ be the lowest value of $F(x)$ in the $i$th interval of $\Delta x$.  The sum $L_n = \Sigma m_i\Delta x$ is a lower bound for the true answer.
In the same way, let $M_i$ be the highest value of $F(x)$ in the $i$th interval.  Then $U_n=\Sigma M_i\Delta x$ is an upper bound for the true answer.
If $F(x)$ is always increasing, or if it is always decreasing, then $$|U_n-L_n|\le 
\left(\max(F(x))-\min(F(x))\right)\Delta x$$
So, as $\Delta x\to0$, the upper bounds and lower bounds approach the same value.
If $F(x)$ increases and decreases a finite number of times, the difference between the upper bounds and the lower bounds still approaches zero.  The integral is the only number left between all the lower bounds and all the upper bounds.